# Enumerating each IP address assigned to network interfaces

Tags: c, windows, linux, sockets, networking

I think there is no way to enumerate each network interface on my system and their assigned IP address using just sockets. Is this correct?

I mean, in Linux this could be:

```
eth0: 192.168.1.5
wlan0: 192.168.0.5
lo: 127.0.0.1
```

I don't care about interface names, just the IP addresses assigned.

I recall to have done this in the past in Windows, using [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) (though I don't remember how). But is there a method to do this in a portable way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a good start:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void
print_sockaddr(struct sockaddr* addr,const char *name)
{
    char addrbuf[128] ;

    addrbuf[0] = 0;
    if(addr->sa_family == AF_UNSPEC)
        return;
    switch(addr->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET:
            inet_ntop(addr->sa_family,&((struct sockaddr_in*)addr)->sin_addr,addrbuf,sizeof(addrbuf));
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            inet_ntop(addr->sa_family,&((struct sockaddr_in6*)addr)->sin6_addr,addrbuf,sizeof(addrbuf));
            break;
        default:
            sprintf(addrbuf,"Unknown (%d)",(int)addr->sa_family);
            break;

    }
    printf("%-16s %s\n",name,addrbuf);
}

void
print_ifaddr(struct ifaddrs *addr)
{
    char addrbuf[128] ;

    addrbuf[0] = 0;
    printf("%-16s %s\n","Name",addr->ifa_name);
    if(addr->ifa_addr != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_addr,"Address");
    if(addr->ifa_netmask != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_netmask,"Netmask");
    if(addr->ifa_broadaddr != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_broadaddr,"Broadcast addr.");
    if(addr->ifa_dstaddr != NULL)
        print_sockaddr(addr->ifa_dstaddr,"Peer addr.");
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct ifaddrs *addrs,*tmp;

    if(getifaddrs(&addrs) != 0) {
        perror("getifaddrs");
        return 1;
    }
    for(tmp = addrs; tmp ; tmp = tmp->ifa_next) {
        print_ifaddr(tmp);
    }

    freeifaddrs(addrs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is just what I needed, thanks!! but it only works on linux, am I right? what cuold be the the winapi equivalent?

Comment: `GetAdapterAddresses()` and related functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gethostname()` to retreive the machine's local DNS name, and then pass that name to `gethostbyname()` to get its local IP addresses.

If the OS supports IPv6, then look at the `getaddrinfo()` function instead of `gethostbyname()`.

Comment: here I've manually edited the hostname to resolve to my static LAN IP address (lets say 192.168.0.2) but how exactly this behaves on another systems? I mean.. does the hostname resolve to 127.0.0.1 or to what IP of which interface by default?

Comment: Calling `gethostbyname()` with an IP address as the hostname will not work, AFAIK.  You could use `gethostbyaddr()` instead, but that will return a `hostent` structure that contains only the IP you originally specified.  To enumerate the available IPs, you have to use the machine's actual hostname.  Otherwise, you will have to use OS-specific APIs to enumerate the network interfaces directly (on Windows, look at `GetAdapterAddresses()` and related functions).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ioctl()` function. If I recall correctly, you can use it to obtain information on any interface, as well as obtaining the available interfaces.

I don't remember the correct invocation though. As with `fcntl()`, it takes a request argument plus variable parameters that determine its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, that information is accessed through NETLINK sockets. See the manual pages for libnetlink(3), netlink(7) and rtnetlink(7).

A somewhat more portable way of doing this is via ioctl()'s. SIOCGIFCONF is the one you want. See the manual page for netdevice(7). This one works on some other *nixes.