# Want to get the list all the available interfaces on the system

Tags: ubuntu, networking, c

I want to get the list all the available interfaces on a particular PC along with their types that is wired or wireless. Currently I am doing the following but no success:-

```
ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFNAME, &ifr);
strncpy(ifname,ifr.ifr_name,IFNAMSIZ);
printf("Interface name :%s\n",ifname);
```

It will also be good if only names are available.

Comment: Getting the type of interface might be hard, but enumerating the interfaces(and their addresses) is pretty straight foreward see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021549/get-ip-address-in-c-language or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909656/enumerating-each-ip-assigned-to-network-interfaces/3909936

Answer (score 20):

If you're on ubuntu, as your tags indicate, you can always read `/proc/net/dev` which has the information you're looking for in it.

Answer (score 12):

```
ifconfig -a
```

for all you can see interfaces avalaible lists you don't need script for C code for this,

İf you wanna more information for your interfaces

```
lspci
```

You can find your interfaces type and models

Answer (score 4):

The C interface is called **ifaddrs**, you may include it with:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
```

The functions you are interested in are [`getifaddrs`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getifaddrs) and once done with the data, [`freeifaddrs`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freeifaddrs).

```
struct ifaddrs {
    struct ifaddrs  *ifa_next;    /* Next item in list */
    char            *ifa_name;    /* Name of interface */
    unsigned int     ifa_flags;   /* Flags from SIOCGIFFLAGS */
    struct sockaddr *ifa_addr;    /* Address of interface */
    struct sockaddr *ifa_netmask; /* Netmask of interface */
    union {
        struct sockaddr *ifu_broadaddr;
                         /* Broadcast address of interface */
        struct sockaddr *ifu_dstaddr;
                         /* Point-to-point destination address */
    } ifa_ifu;
#define              ifa_broadaddr ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr
#define              ifa_dstaddr   ifa_ifu.ifu_dstaddr
    void            *ifa_data;    /* Address-specific data */
};
```

This structure includes all the info as the `ifconfig` command line tool returns.

For C++ users, I suggest you use a deleter like this:

```
void ifaddrs_deleter(struct ifaddrs * ia)
{
    freeifaddrs(ia);
}
```

And attach the result of `getifaddrs()` to it with:

```
struct ifaddrs * ifa_start(nullptr);
if(getifaddrs(&ifa_start) != 0)
{
    return;
}
// will automatically delete on exception or any return
std::shared_ptr<struct ifaddrs> auto_free(ifa_start, ifaddrs_deleter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use this command for Ubuntu. I am not sure if this work for other distribution.

```
ls /sys/class/net
```